# (MQL5) How to show All Ticket in Combobox?

Tags: combobox, mql5, metatrader5

How to show All Ticket in Combobox?
i opened 3 order buy EA only show one-order in Combobox.
m_combobox_box.ItemsClear(); ////When i remove it all order show, but collect endless!

```
void CControlsDialog::Update(void){

//Print(__FUNCTION__);

 //int     ticketread1 = 9999;
for(int i = PositionsTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      long ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
      if(ticket>0){
          PositionSelectByTicket(ticket);
          ENUM_POSITION_TYPE posType = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
          //Print(EnumToString(posType) + " : " + (string)ticketRead);
          Print((string)ticket);
          
          m_combobox_box.ItemsClear(); ////When i remove it all order show, but collect endless items.
          m_combobox_box.ItemAdd(ticket);

      }
   }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df9rd.png)
[after remove .ItemsClear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3GI9.png)

how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing the `m_combobox_box.ItemsClear();` before the iteration?

```
m_combobox_box.ItemsClear();
for(int i = PositionsTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```